# Unzip File On Google Drive Using PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api, unzip

I'm developing a web app where users could upload .zip file and storing it in the Google Drive. The upload part was easy but I have no clue how to unzip the file uploaded.

I found [this](https://zip-extractor.appspot.com/) but it's in Javascript and am still trying to find out how to unzip the file using PHP. Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the [ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php), i.e.:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('myfile.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/extract/path/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'ok!';
} else {
  echo 'error!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think we could use $zip->extractTo('/extract/path/'); to extract files to Drive, or can we ? Because reading from the doc, we should use Google_DriveFile class for uploading file.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a solution, I don't think unzipping files on Drive using PHP is possible by now. So instead of uploading .zip, I extract the zip to temp folder then loop to read the files. Here are the steps I do :

```
    loop items in folderId as item
        if item == folder
            create folder on Drive
            fetch folder id as folderId
            loop(folderId)
        else if item == file
            file.parent = folderId
            upload file
        endif
    endloop
```